# Encrypted password not being sent to mongoDB on registration, login also not finding data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication, passwords

As stated, when I register an account on testing mongo is receiving the user, email, phone just fine, but there is no encrypted password, despite the documentation I followed showing otherwise on their testing.

```
require("./registration")

const User = mongoose.model("UserInfo");

// register
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
const { user, email, phone, password } = req.body;

const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
try {

    const oldEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (oldEmail) {
        return res.json({ error: "This email already exists" })
    }
    await User.create({
        user,
        email,
        phone,
        password: encryptedPassword,
    });
    res.send({ status: "Ok" })
} catch (error) {
    res.send({ status: "error" });
}
});
```

The "./registration":

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    user: {type: String, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    phone: String,
    Password: String,
    joined: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
},
{
    collection: "UserInfo",
}
);

mongoose.model("UserInfo", UserDetailsSchema);
```

and the frontend bit:

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/register", {
    method: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      user,
      email,
      phone,
      password,
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data, "userRegister");
      if (data.status === "Ok") {
        setSuccess(true)
        return;
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
    });
  // console.log(user, phone, password);
}
}
```

So I am getting success all around checking console etc, otherwise it is just not showing a encrypted password on mongoDB. As for the login itself it's acting like it is just not finding the registered email at all throwing the "User not found" error I have in place.

```
// login
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;

const user = await User.findOne({ email });
if (!user) {
    return res.json({ error: "User not found" });
}
if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ email: user.email }, JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "15m",
    });

    if (res.status(201)) {
        return res.json({ status: "ok", data: token });
    } else {
        return res.json({ error: "error" });
    }
}
res.json({ status: "error", error: "Invalid Password" })
});
```

Front-end connection:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(email, password);
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/Login", {
        method: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data, "userRegister");
            if (data.status === "ok") {
                setSuccess(true)
                alert("Login Successful");
                window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.data);
                window.localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
            }
        });
}
```

I appreciate any insight given, and thank you for your time reviewing this.

Comment: Why does the `password` start with a capital letter in mongoose model?

Comment: It's always the little typos like that that are getting me! I looked over all this so many times without catching that too, Thank you!